# Is a literal interpretation of Hebrews 9:27 contradictory to a literal interpretation of Revelation 21:8

Tags: contradiction

Hebrews 9:27
King James Version

> 27 And as it is appointed unto men once to die, but after this the judgment:

However we have Revelation 21:8 that literally says some persons will die a second time:

Revelation 21:8
King James Version

> 8 But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death.

Does a literal interpretation of Hebrews 9:27 lead to a contradiction?

Comment: "second death" in Rev 21:8 is uncontroversial.  It clearly refers to the death *after* the physical death that is experienced by everyone while on earth.  Second death is after the Day of Judgment, which hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple So your saying -- appointed to die once, then die, get judged, die again makes sense.

Comment: Yes.  I have expanded my comment into an answer.

Comment: the LDS believe that death is separation and so the referenced scripture would refer to those who are separated from God's presence after judgment.

Comment: @depperm Yes I understand now it's two different senses of the term die/death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not contradictory since the meaning of "second death" in Rev 21:8 is uncontroversial: death because of punishment after the Day of Judgment, *not* another earthly death after a soul has been reincarnated.  "Second death" has a very different nature than the earthly "first death" that has been or will be experienced by everyone while on earth (except Elijah, Enoch, etc.).

From a 2017 blog article by a theology professor Terrance Tiessen [*First and second death: similarities and differences*](https://www.thoughtstheological.com/first-and-second-death-similarities-and-differences/):

> Christians have uniformly affirmed the resurrection of everyone at Christ’s return, and there has been no controversy over what this means for those who died in faith, regardless of the covenant under which they died. Believers, even those whose faith was necessarily pre-Christian (that is, whose response to God was assessed according to an earlier covenant than the new one), are raised with Christ, to enjoy life in the new heaven and earth that God establishes after the final judgment. But unbelievers do not participate in the redemption accomplished by Christ, and they are excluded from the gloriously renewed creation. Instead, their destiny is Gehenna, hell, the consuming lake of fire, shame and contempt. By contrast with the righteous in Christ, who are given immortality and eternal life, those who are condemned are punished with the second death (Rev 2:11, 20:6, 14, and 21:8).

Terrance also said something about how Jesus's resurrection is **NOT** reincarnation:

> It is certain that Jesus was not personally extinguished in his humanity, in death, and then recreated (reincarnated) 3 days later. That would entail 2 incarnations and be a highly irregular Christology. On the other hand, it is important that we not treat Jesus’ situation as unique. In his experience of death and resurrection *for us* he went through the process that we who are “in Christ” also go through, thereby transforming the meaning of death for us and assuring us of the resurrection to glory. It was the eternal Word, who was pure spirit, who took upon himself human nature (i.e., he added to his essential divine attributes the essential human attributes). What matters for us here, is the continued personal existence of Jesus as both God and man, after his bodily death, which, in the manner Jesus experienced death as a human being, was no different from that of every other human being. As the Definition of Chalcedon put it, in being begotten of the virgin Mary, the eternal Son of God became a man “like us in all respects apart from sin,” and this pertained equally to his experience between death and resurrection.

Another article [Does the Second Death imply Reincarnation](https://www.biblia.work/sermons/does-the-second-death-imply-reincarnation-bible-study/) provides a typical exegesis of the meaning of "second death" (emphasis mine):

> When Jesus spoke to the church at Smyrna (Revelation 2:8-10) and warned of future trials they would face, he encouraged them to be “faithful unto death,” that is, possess the martyr spirit that was essential to their being victorious with the Lord (cf. Revelation 6:9-11; Revelation 7:13-15). Jesus assures them that the ones who “overcome” will not be hurt by “the second death” (Revelation 2:11 – KJV).
>
> Note that the associated word “hurt” necessarily says something about the meaning of the phrase, “second death.” The use of this phrase does not allow the idea that there will be another chance, just in case we don’t “get it right” the first time. It is identifiable with what “hurts” men, and is relative to some kind of punishment not what is beneficial to man.
>
> This phrase does not appear again in Revelation until Revelation 20:6 and Revelation 20:14. In this text, let us focus on “the second death” as it used with reference to punishment.
>
> This time, it is identifiable with the eternal state of the enemies of Christ death (the enemy of man 1 Corinthians 15:26) and Hades (the unseen abiding place of the dead) are cast into the lake of fire as are the beast (the corrupt, persecuting political power) and the false prophet (false religion) note Revelation 20:10.
>
> Then noting Revelation 21:8 we read, “But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death.”
>
> **Those who believe in reincarnation really do not want to use this verse, because it clearly speaks of “the second death” as a place of irrevocable punishment the lake that burns with fire and brimstone (Revelation 20:10)**.

Comment: I'm sorry. I removed my connection to reincarnation in the question, since it confused the question.  Though my motivation is to show that the Hebrews passage should not be taken literally, and my interest area is reincarnation, The question stands on its own.   It appears to me that some men die twice.

Comment: @scm No need to apologize.  Yes, that edit makes the question more focused, and I hope my answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s read the following very carefully.

Rev 20:4  And I saw thrones, and they sat upon them, and judgment was given unto them: and I saw the souls of them that were beheaded for the witness of Jesus, and for the word of God, and which had not worshipped the beast, neither his image, neither had received his mark upon their foreheads, or in their hands; and they lived and reigned with Christ a thousand years.
Rev 20:5  But the rest of the dead lived not again until the thousand years were finished. This is the first resurrection.
Rev 20:6 Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection: on such the second death hath no power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years.

Notice in verse 4 it says the martyrs that did not receive the Mark of the Beast would reign with Christ for 1000 years in his Kingdom.  Verse 5 says that all the rest of the dead who were not martyred would  not be resurrected until the 1000 yr period was over. So to sum it up, the first resurrection consisted of only martyrs.

At that time is when the beast and the false prophet are cast into the lake of fire according to :

Rev 19:20 And the beast was taken, and with him the false prophet that wrought miracles before him, with which he deceived them that had received the mark of the beast, and them that worshipped his image. These both were cast alive into a lake of fire burning with brimstone.

Now there are other nations that exist before, during, and after the 1000 yr reign of Christ the King. We  know that from verse 8 saying that after the 1000 years Satan would “deceive the nations which are in the four quarters of the earth”. We don’t know for how long Satan deceives these various nations but at some point in time God comes and destroys Satan and cast him in the lake of fire with the beast & the false prophet. (Rev 20:10). During the time period that Satan was free to deceive those nations, we can only assume that many died in sin as well as many who died that had kept God’s commandments and did not sin. Then we get to Rev 20:11 where we have the great white throne judgement. Here we see all the rest of the dead who were not in the first resurrection prior to the 1000yr and the dead who died in other nations after the 1000 yr when Satan was loosed, being judged with the book of life opened. This is when those not in the book of life are cast in the lake of fire. (Rev 20:14, 15). This is known as the second death because many of the ones not resurrected with the martyrs prior to the 1000 yrs, were sinners who were resurrected at the great white judgement that took place after the 1000 plus years and they were cast into the lake of fire. Thus they physically died twice, …. years before the beginning of the 1000 yrs and years after the 1000 yr.

Comment: You have glossed over the time after the 1000 years when the rest are resurrected - not to die again by default, but to be judged and be offered their first opportunity for salvation. Otherwise, fair effort.

Comment: Yes Steve. I overlooked that part. At the end of Rev 20 it doesn't specifically say that the sinless ones who were judged from the Book of Life lived for eternity but it is to be understood that they did because it says "whosoever was not found in the Book of life was cast in the lake of fire" Thus we can only conclude that the ones that were found in the Book lived.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.  Hebrews 9:27 refers only to the sinless who die before or after the 1000yr. Verse 28 clarifies this by the sinless one time death of Christ.